# {{link-to}} within a model's attribute?

Tags: ember.js

Given something like a `post` model with a `body` attribute, is there a way to get ember to dynamically render `{{link-to}}`'s within the `body` attribute?

Example:

```
// The model
post = {
  body: `
    {{#link-to "posts.index"}}
      <h1>The "{{#link-to}}" is rendered literally!</h1>
    {{/link-to}}`
}

// The .hbs file
<div class="container">
  {{postBody post.body}}
</div>

// Helper function to avoid escaping the HTML
export function postBody(postBody) {
  return Ember.String.htmlSafe(postBody);
}
export default Ember.Helper.helper(postBody);
```

The only thing I can think to do is enter a static link, which would cause a full page reload.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think this is possible any more after the switch to HTMLbars. You might be able to compile the template client-side but I'm not sure inserting it into the DOM would be easy. Either way, would you mind explaining what your use case is? Even if this is possible, it shouldn't be done.

Comment: Hey @GJK. I think you're right on all accounts. My use case is that I have blog post models. I'd like to store the bodies of each post in the model, and the posts might refer to past posts. Ideally this would be done with a link-to to avoid a full page refresh.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Do you have control of how the posts are saved? I've done something similar to this before and the way I solved it was by putting placeholders in the text and storing metadata along with the text. Then, at runtime, I used the router to generate the URL and insert that where the placeholders were. That is a bit orthogonal to this question, but it's a possibility if you can't figure this method out.

Comment: Thanks @GJK! I do have control over the posts and will go with this for now. Please feel free to put this in an answer and I'll mark it as solved since there isn't yet a native solution.

Comment: I'm a bit busy now but when I find some time in the next few hours I'll type up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `compile` function. See [here](http://www.ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_compile) for more information. You would call it like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.compile(this.get('post.body');
```

Comment: Note that Ember stopped using Handlebars in 1.10. This won't work for newer versions.